# RSYNC from remote to local excluding folders

Tags: rsync, remote, copy, localization

How can I download from a remote server to local excluding folders or files?

I have used something like this but the exclude doesn't work...

```
rsync -avr -P -e ssh --exclude=/path/to/exclude/* user@ipaddress:/home/path/to/copy /home/user/www
```

Suggestions?

Comment: I can't do reverse operation (launch rsync from my remote server to copy files to my local server) because I can't remote open my local server.

Comment: Did you protect globstar '*' from expansion with single quotes?

Comment: yes, also used: rsync -avr -P -e ssh --exclude="/path/to/exclude/*" user@ipaddress:/home/path/to/copy /home/user/www

Answer (score 7):

The problem here is likely to be with the paths in the `exclude` filters in rsync.

The paths used in the rsync file list are *relative* to the SOURCE path.

That is if your directory structure is

```
 /home/path/to/copy
                | files_to_copy
                     | file1
                     \ file2
                \ files_to_exclude
                     | file3
                     \ file4
```

Then if you issue the command

```
rsync -avr -e ssh user@host:/home/path/to/copy \
                 /home/user/www --exclude='files_to_exclude/*'
```

You will get the following structure in the copy

```
 /home/user/www
             | files_to_copy
                  | file1
                  \ file2
             \ files_to_exclude
```

If you do not want to have the directory `files_to_exclude` in the copy you may use the following command:

```
rsync -avr -e ssh user@host:/home/path/to/copy \
                 /home/user/www --exclude='files_to_exclude'
```

Answer (score 0):

We use something similar to this

```
filename=`date +%F`_backup
rsync --verbose --log-file=/backup_logs/"$filename" --progress --stats --compress --rsh=/usr/bin/ssh --recursive --times --perms --links --delete --exclude '*.zip' user@remoteMachine:/data/documents/ /local/data/documents/
```